# how to run informix dbexport from java code

Tags: java, informix

I have a list of data transformations that I have to apply to Informix database through java code, but first I need to backup my db before any data manipulation. 
Now I am doing this manually: 
1. run "dbexport [dbname]" on command line
2. check that dbexport was successful (I just look at the log in cmd and see if there are any errors)
3. if everything is OK java program is started

Now I would like to automate this process. My question is how to execute dbexport from java code and most importantly how to verify that dbexport was successful? 
Additional question: my db can be locked from time to time from another app so "dbexport [dbname]" returns exception "database locked." and stops executing. I would like to get this info in my java code and delay the export process for some time. Is there maybe a library for stuff like this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to directly call dbexport from Java, but I know you can execute a command on the OS this way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command here...");
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("");
p.waitFor();

// Read the lines generated by the execution
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Maybe you can call your dbexport this way, and once it finishes, you just go and read your log (can be done from Java too), and if everything is ok, you just continue what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could call any OS command through the SYSTEM statement. Check in IBM Knowledge Center for your specific OS and Informix version.

Hope it helps.
Regards.